# Trouble parsing and updating variables in Batch script, out of and within FOR-Loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I am trying to build a Windows batch file which should do the following:

- Take the reference image (it should be the first image by taking into account the numeration `ima_0001.png`, `ima_0002.png`...).
- In the second step, the `FOR` structure takes the images in the sequence (e.g.: `ima_0001.png`, `imag_002.png`, ...), calls a function to compare images from another batch file, and updates the reference image with the current image `%defa%`.

The script performs nearly well except for two major steps:

1. I can't set the reference or first file directly with `set "defa=ima_0001.png"`
   I tried in different ways: `defa=ima_0001.png`, `defa=!ima_0001.png!`, without success.
   So finally I decided to leave the `FOR` structure selecting one which does not coincide with the first numbered (it takes `ima_0064.png` and not `ima_0001.png`)
   I thank somebody who can help me to set the first one whether manually or automatically.
2. The worst part is that the second `FOR` structure does not change the reference image with the
   line `set "defa=%%h"`.
   For example, after the first cycle `FOR`, `defa` should change from `ima_0001.png` to `ima_0002.png`, or from `ima_0064.png` to `ima_0065.png`. However, when console runs, `%%h` changes, but `defa` always shows the first image, (`ima_0064.png`). I also tried different ways without success, as well as setting `setlocal` or not setting it.
   I thank somebody who can give me notions to solve his issue.

The script is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd C:\Users\docs

set/a "th=870"
REM Set the first file or take one with FOR 
::set "defa=ima_0001.png"
FOR %%m in (1,1,*.png) do set "defa=%%m"
REM BUCLE DE LLAMADA A LA FUNCIÓN Callme
FOR %%h in (*.png) DO (
    Callme "%defa%" "%%h" %th%
    set "defa=%%h"
)
pause
```

Comment: `FOR %%m in (1,1,*.png) do` - it looks like you mixed the syntaxes for a pur `for` and a `for /L` to get the first (alphabetical) file: `for /f "delims=" %%m in ('dir /b /on') do if not defined defa set "defa=%%m"` (be sure `defa` is undefined before entering the loop)

Comment: Thank you Stephan. Now the first value of defa is just the first file ima_ooo1.png

Comment: What is `Callme`? An application (.exe)? Another batch script?

Comment: Thank you Stephan. Now the first file coincided with the first one in the numeric order, although I have a new problem that I'll post in a new question.

Comment: Yes, Callme is a function another batch file that apply to the file parsed by the second for structure.

Comment: batchfiles have to be `call`ed, else they don't return: `call callme.bat "!defa!" "%%h" %th%`